# Using CasperJs with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, testing, requirejs, casperjs, functional-testing

I'd like to write a functional test on my webpage using CasperJS, that:

1. Fills login form
2. Submits login form
3. Checks for dynamically loaded content

The first two steps I've already manage to do, but I have a problem with the third one. The HTML structure I get after logging in is not quite the one I can see inside, i.e. Chrome developer console. Some content is missing - it's like I would only get structure available inside my index.html file, but nothing more.

Here is my code for testing:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var loginForm = 'form[name="login"]';
var orderMenuItem = '.rst-menu-orders';

casper.start('https://mywebpageaddress.com/');

casper.waitForSelector(loginForm, function(){
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    this.fillSelectors(loginForm, {
        'input[name="username"]': '1234',
        'input[name="password"]': '1234'
    }, true);
});

casper.thenOpen('http://mywebpageaddress.com/subpage', function(){
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());

    this.waitForSelector('.rst-tab-menu-element', function() {
        this.echo(document.querySelectorAll('.rst-tab-menu-element').length);
    });
});

casper.run();
```

So every time I run this test I get message that timeout of 5000 ms expired, which means, that the `'.rst-tab-menu-element'` is not there, but I know that it exists in the DOM, because I can see it in Chrome ie.

I've already tried to wait for 20000ms hoping for content to load, but it seems, that the problem is something else. I'm using Require JS to load my javascript files and I was wondering - maybe this could be an issue? I'd be grateful for some tips on how I can make this work.

I also get reference errors:

```
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: requirejs
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Have you dumped the page source to see what is loaded? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you.I get refference errorso now at least I know what's wrong.

Comment: This probably means that some script could not be loaded. Have you tried running as `casperjs --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false script.js`? Could you add the errors to your question?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I added error. I guess I have to inject missing scripts. I've tried run test with those flags, but I get same errors.

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use by the way and have you tried upgrading to 2.0.0?

Comment: I am using version 1.9.8. I'll try on with 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

With the above suggestions to debug errors, it is much easier to find potential issues.

In addition, an alternative to always use and I will suggest is the use of CasperJS tests module:

```
casper.test.begin('test script', 0, function(test) {
    casper.start(url);

    casper.then(function myFunction(){
        //...
    });

    casper.run(function () {
        //...
        test.done();
    });
});
```

If you want to inject scripts, you can use, for example:

```
phantom.injectJs('C:/casperjs/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js');
```

In addition, the test module, stay tuned to the use of some items, such as:
`document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` to be used along with

```
this.evaluate(function () {
    //...
});
```

so, it avoids the DOM rendering problems.

I hope my suggestions can help in your future scripts!